# SLF4J logs are not coming in the specific error/trace file. It is coming in server.log

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, executorservice

I am programming in Java. I have used executor service. Logs are printing in the specified trace.log file for the main thread. But for the threads created by the executor service, logs are getting printed in the Jboss server.log. How to get these logs in the trace.log instead of in server.log?

I found the concurrency should not affect the functionality of slf4j.
[Is SLF4J good to be used in a multithreaded application for logging to a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159141/is-slf4j-good-to-be-used-in-a-multithreaded-application-for-logging-to-a-databas)

Could somebody please tell what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude SLF4J from JBoss. You can do it with jboss-deployment-structure.xml

My jboss-deployment-structure is located in EAR module under resources/META-INF folder and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
<deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.slf4j" slot="main" />
        <module name="org.slf4j.impl" slot="main" />
    </exclusions>
</deployment>

<sub-deployment name="some-war.war">
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.slf4j" />
        <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
    </exclusions>
</sub-deployment>
```

In `some-war.war` module I can use logback which logs properly into defined files.